# grunt.task.run() is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, gruntjs

Im trying to use grunt inside my express application.

I have something like this:

```
var grunt = require('grunt');
require(process.cwd() + '/gruntfile.js')(grunt);
grunt.task.run('development');
```

But the task seems that is not wokring. (no error is outputed to the console)
But if I run directly in console "grunt development" it works fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`grunt.task.run` just adds a task to the queue, so it works within an existing task, but not within an external script. Here's a simple technique I've borrowed from `grunt/lib/grunt/cli.js`. Beware--it's not part of [the official API](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/wiki/grunt). [Grunt issue 687](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/687) notes the need for an official API for this feature.

```
var grunt = require('grunt');
process.chdir(__dirname);
var config = require('./Gruntfile');
config(grunt);
console.log('Minifying...');
grunt.tasks(['cssmin']);
```

Comment: Brilliant! Now I don't need to install grunt-cli!

Comment: How can I pass additional grunt params like --force or --verbose in this scenario?